# Css part of fixed side nav hidden when the main content shorter from the nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have side nav and main content. Both are dynamic. The problem is when the nav is longer than the main content its height set to the viewport height, and the rest hidden, How can I solve this issue without ugly scroller to the navigation?

**I need the nav to be fixed**

```css
section {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 250px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
          flex: 0 0 250px;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
}

main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
      <li>21</li>
      <li>22</li>
      <li>23</li>
      <li>24</li>
      <li>25</li>
      <li>26</li>
      <li>27</li>
      <li>28</li>
      <li>29</li>
      <li>30</li>
      <li>31</li>
      <li>32</li>
      <li>33</li>
      <li>34</li>
      <li>35</li>
      <li>36</li>
      <li>37</li>
      <li>38</li>
      <li>39</li>
      <li>40</li>
      <li>41</li>
      <li>42</li>
      <li>43</li>
      <li>44</li>
      <li>45</li>
      <li>46</li>
      <li>47</li>
      <li>48</li>
      <li>49</li>
      <li>50</li>
      <li>51</li>
      <li>52</li>
      <li>53</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur tenetur tempore voluptatum quasi architecto accusamus sapiente quaerat sequi ratione optio eos, accusantium corrupti dolor aliquid similique culpa libero officiis atque?</p>
  </main>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky because a fixed position element is removed from the document flow, so its height is being ignored.

You could absolutely position the nav bar, then use a media query to switch to fixed positioning when the window gets smaller.

Or you could use Javascript.

Here are some ways others have done it:

- [Fixed sidebar too tall for browser (bottom is getting cut off)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9611044/3597276)
- [CSS: sidebar with fixed position getting cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6297134/3597276)
- [How to stick fixed div of height more than viewport to body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25996585/3597276)
- [Problems when the element to be fixed is itself higher then the browser window height](https://www.drupal.org/node/1878258)